# Should I test if a "wrapper layout" component passes props to children components that were already tested?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, integration-testing, react-testing-library

I'm building a blog page, it has a `Sidebar` and a `Posts` component, both are unit tested to check if they are rendering the proper data passed by props (both are pure components).

I had to create a wrapper component called `BlogLayout` because I was repeating some code at some points. `BlogLayout` receives posts and categories as props, which then will be just passed down to `Sidebar` and `Posts` components, and just renders both components with some styling.

**The problem is:** I don't know how I'm supposed to test the `BlogLayout` component. Its whole purpose is to only pass received props down to the `Sidebar` and `Posts` components (it will pass categories and posts as props).

**My points and questions regarding the situation:**

- If I test if `BlogLayout` renders the categories and posts (as UI data), I would just be repeating the exact same tests I have in both components. Should I do it anyway?
- If I consider not to test it because it's just repeated code, I might have problems in case I don't pass these props down to the components. They will work as units, but won't work together in the app.
- My solution to this would be to unit test `BlogLayout` to check ONLY if it's passing down the correct props to the child components. This way I would have a much simpler test, since knowing that the props were passed down I can be completely sure that the child components will handle it properly since they are tested for that. Is that possible?

I'm using `react-testing-library` for the tests.

Any contribution to help me get to the best solution is much appreciated, I'm far from being an experienced developer regarding tests, so I might have some wrong thoughts on them here.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: *Should I do it anyway?* - depends on the approach. With functional tests you should. *Is that possible?* - mock children with dummy components and assert that they receive props and render correctly.

Comment: @estus That's the thinking I have, but how would mocking the children help to know if they received the correct props? I can only make assertions based on elements when using `react-testing-library`, which means I would repeat the tests. So maybe my main question here is: what's the preferred approach in this situation when using `react-testing-library`? I'm thinking that maybe in this situation I should not use it so I can get a reference to the children components and not only DOM elements.

Comment: Mock components so dummy components would pass props directly to DOM and you could assert results with selectors. Since react-testing-library is heavily opinionated towards functional testing, WET tests are likely preferred but this doesn't mean that you have to do this. I personally wouldn't.

Comment: I see, it would make it easier depending on the complexity of the children components, but still I would have to have at least do some mapping to render array props, simulate events in case I'm also passing cb functions, and probably more cases which just complicates this more. I think I'll go off the `react-testing-library` on these kind of tests. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Enzyme to check if the props were being passed down to the components, so the final test ended up like this:

```
it(`passes down the correct props to child components`, () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<BlogLayout {...props} />);
  expect(wrapper.find(Sidebar).props().categories).toMatchObject(props.categories);
  expect(wrapper.find(Sidebar).props().currentCategory).toMatchObject(props.currentCategory);
});
```

I imagined that the best way to test this component is to just check if the correct props are being passed to its children. But to do this using `react-testing-library` would make me simply just repeat the unit tests already defined in both child components (they are tested to render their props properly). So Enzyme helps me to find the instance of each child component and just check if their props are the same as the one passed to the tested component.

This way I don't repeat myself in different tests, and still have the confidence that my app is working as intended.

If someone has any more thoughts on this or a better solution, I would be extremely happy to try and update the correct answer if I find it to be actually better.

Comment: I like your approach. I was just wondering if there are any disadvantages to this approach. I also want to know if there is any conflict between `react-testing-library` and `enzyme`?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first point: For example if you have 2 props:

- categories - prop
- posts - props

You should pass both props into declaration - of wrapper.

**1)** And make one test which will verify does post are render correctly.

**2)** The other test which will check does categories are rendered correctly.

**Expected result**: Then if categories are not rendered you will know where is the problem exactly.

Comment: I've updated the beginning of my post with some more information. I'm receiving posts and categories as props in the wrapper component. If I test in the wrapper component if posts (a list of articles with title, image, etc.) and Sidebar (a list of categories with text and href) are being rendered properly, I'll repeat the exact same tests I have for those components.
That's why I think it would make more sense to just test if the wrapper component is passing down the received props to its children, but I'm not sure if that's possible or which other way should I go using react-testing-library.